# meaning of a Modulo class

Tags: math, cryptography, modulo, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to implement Paillier Cryptosystem in Java and facing a doubt with the definition of the modulo set WITH A STAR. Specifically, what do we mean if we add a star to Zn?

I am confused between two:

1) It is the set of prime numbers.
2) It is the set Zn minus the element zero.

Google search didnt help. At least not to me.

[image]

Comment: This is off-topic; the answer is more likely to be found in your textbook (or whatever the source of that tiny image is) than here on SO.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark this is the source of the image 

[link] (http://enpub.fulton.asu.edu/sensip/SenSIP_Papers/PrivateMatching%20_yanchao.pdf)' '

I have searched a lot of textbooks, referred a prof. too, and searched thoroughly in the paper, but no clue is there.

Comment: If `R` is a ring, like `Z_n`, the notation `R^*` (the `^` is meant to indicate that the asterisk is elevated) usually means the group of units in `R`, i.e. the group of elements that have a multiplicative inverse. Occasionally, the notation means the set of non-zero elements of the ring, but in the context of cryptography, I would be surprised if that were the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Daniel Fischer (Z_n)* is the unit group of Z_n. Practically speaking, (Z_n)* is the set of integers x, 1 <= x < n, such that GCD(x,n) = 1.

Comment: I dont know if your answer is correct but is the set of x GCD(x,n) = 1 equivalent to the set of all those x for which there exists a multiplicative inverse in the set Zn ??

Comment: @rajatIIT:  Yes, it is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This is number theory notation used in cryptography. Note that cryptographers usually use notation that is slightly different from modern number theory. There is a good introduction to number theory for cryptographers [part one](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cs255/handouts/numth2.pdf) and [part two](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cs255/handouts/numth1.pdf) available at Stanford's Introduction to Cryptography course.  [Part two](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cs255/handouts/numth1.pdf) of that sheet discusses `(Z_n)*`.

If you want to know more about number theory in general, I found [Contemporary Abstract Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0395861799) to be really helpful during my cryptography classes.